# MAUI: ListView Binding With Custom ViewCell

Tags: c#, listview, maui

I use FreshMvvm to develop and run MAUI project on Windows.

But I have some binding issues with ListView and my custom template.

The following is my code:

Model:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
}

public class NameModel: BaseModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    private readonly IApiService _apiService;
    private List<NameModel> _nameModelList;

    public List<NameModel> NameModelList
    {
        get => _nameModelList;
        private set 
        {
            _nameModelList= value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(NameModelList));
        }
    }

    public MainPageModel(IApiService apiService)
    {
        _apiService = apiService;
    }

    protected override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);

        Task.Run(() => GetNameData());
    }

    private async Task GetNameData()
    {
        var result = await _apiService.GetNameData();
        NameModelList= result.GetRange(1, 10);
    }
}
```

I create a list and use an api service to get a name model list data.
If api service gets the data, `NameModelList` will be updated.

`NameModelList` is the property which will be bind on Listview.ItemsSource

MainPage.xmal:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewCells.CustomListViewCell"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.Pages.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}">

    <Grid RowSpacing="25" 
          RowDefinitions="Auto" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ListView 
                x:Name="MyListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding NameModelList}"
                Grid.Row="0"
                WidthRequest="800"
                HeightRequest="800"
                BackgroundColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:MyCustomViewCell/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Custom ViewCell (.xml):

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="MyNamespace.ViewCells.CustomListViewCell.MyCustomViewCell">

    <Grid RowSpacing="100"  WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout
            GridLayout.Row="0"
            GridLayout.Column="0">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding Code}"
                FontSize="30"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                FontSize="30"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Custom ViewCell (.cs)

```
public partial class MyCustomViewCell: ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CodeProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create("Code", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomViewCell), "");

    public string Code
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CodeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomViewCell), "");

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I define a custom ViewCell files and put this ViewCell in the Listview of MainPage.

Now my question is my Listview can't show data successfully.

I'm sure that `NameModelList` has value and its count is more than 1.

But I can see nothing.

The output log has no error, and the breakpoints in `MyCustomViewCell.cs` are never triggered.

So I think I have some binding issues, but I can't find it out.

Comment: I'd start by using a basic TextCell with hardcoded values.  This will rule out problems with your binding and your custom ViewCell

Comment: I think you have to still do this: `<local:MyCustomViewCell Code="{Binding Code}" Name="{Binding Name}" />`

Comment: @Jason I will try TextCell. Thanks!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Actually I did it. But the message about 'property not found' came out.

Comment: @Jason TextCell is working. but if I want to make more custom stuffs, like use Grid and put images and texts in second column. I think this case should use ViewCell to achieve.

Comment: my suggestion was intended to rule out any underlying data problems, which sounds like it worked.  So that means the problem is with your control.  I think @GeraldVersluis is on the right track, and I also believe you need to set the BindingContext of the control to `this`

Comment: @Jason Do you mean ``BindingContext = this`` in ``MyCustomViewCell``? By the way, I set ``ViewCell`` directly in ``ListView``, and the binding is working.

Comment: Please update us with correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to the bottom of this I took your code and put it in a project so I could have a little play with it. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/StackOverflowQuestion70555890Sample). Not to be rude here or anything, but might be a good idea for a next question to do that yourself, that will help speed things up :)

Anyway, the problem is much more subtle. Because you're using XAML for your layout, you'll have to call `InitializeComponent` in the constructor. So adding this to your `MyCustomViewCell` made it work:

```cs
public MyCustomViewCell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I can't call ``InitializeComponent()`` in ``ViewCell``.

Comment: Uploaded the code to my GitHub and added the link to the answer. It would be interesting to see what the difference is with your code then :D

Comment: I got it. I must add ````<ItemGroup><MauiXaml Include="ViewCells\ListView\MyCustomViewCell.xaml"><Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator></MauiXaml></ItemGroup>```` in .csproj file. Now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, slightly different then, I thought something was off because you didn't see the properties and couldn't call InitializeComponent. Glad we got it figured out!

Comment: Can you guys please update with an answer.  Facing how to implement something and I thought maybe custom C# ViewCell, but there's too little info to proceed...