# Warning of binding property not found in MAUI and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my view with MAUI, I get a warning when I populate a `ListView` using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`. The error is

> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'Language' property not found on 'LanguageInUse.ViewModels.DictionaryListViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image.Source'

where `Language` is defined in the *Domain* layer as `Dictionary`:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public SupportedLanguage Language { get; set; }
    public SupportedLanguage LanguageNative { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

I read other posts but I can't find any solution for that:

- [Property not found on target property Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448630/property-not-found-on-target-property-microsoft-maui-controls-label-text)
- [ListView Binding With Custom ViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70555890/maui-listview-binding-with-custom-viewcell)
- [XAML bindings are flagging invalid binding failures](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8433)

I'm facing the same warning but the `ListView` displays the items as expected. I have my XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.ValueConverters"
             xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse"
             xmlns:dt="clr-namespace:LanguageInUseApp.Domain;assembly=LanguageInUseApp.Domain"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Views.DictionaryList"
             x:Name="dictionaryList"
             Title="{lang:Translate Title}">
    <ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionaries}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="dt:Dictionary">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

In my `ContentPage` class I have the constructor

```
DictionaryListViewModel vm;

public DictionaryList(DictionaryListViewModel model)
{
    vm = model;
    BindingContext = vm;
        
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I tried to add in `DataTemplate`, `ViewCell` and in the `Grid` the property `x:DataType="dt:Dictionary"` that is the basic data model I use. The ViewModel has

```
[ObservableProperty] private List<Dictionary> _dictionaries;
```

that is translate in `Dictionaries` in the XAML via `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: you need to specify a `DataType` of Dictionary on the `DataTemplate` element

Comment: yes, I have done it.

Comment: please [edit] your question to show the changes you've made in the code

Comment: I updated the code but, as I said in the last paragraph, I added `x:DataType="dt:Dictionary"` in different places with the same result.

Comment: In the code you show, I don't see any XAML that could generate that error. Do you have `{Binding Language}` somewhere? As Source of an Image? Add to question the XAML element that contains that. And say whether it is inside an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate, or not.

Comment: A side note: `InitializeComponent();` usually comes first by convention.