# How can I add ContextActions to a CollectionView?

Tags: maui

In my `ContextPage` I have a `ListView` that raises errors when I bind the data on it (here the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76723573/warning-of-binding-property-not-found-in-maui-and-communitytoolkit-mvvm)) like this one

> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'Language' property not found on 'LanguageInUse.ViewModels.DictionaryListViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image.Source'

So, people said it is better if I replace the `ListView` with a `CollectionView`. I have done it but there are few things I can't find in a `CollectionView`. The most important thing is the `ContextActions`.

[image]

In a ListView, the user can swipe an element and some options appear in relation to this element or, in a desktop application, a content menu.

Now, I can't find in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/) how to have this kind of menu or if there is another component for it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data#context-menus

Answer (score 2):

Yes,`CollectionView` supports context menus for items of data through the [SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.swipeview?view=net-maui-7.0), which reveals the context menu with a swipe gesture, just as Json mentioned.

This is achieved by setting the `SwipeView` as the root view in the `DataTemplate` that defines the appearance of each item of data in the CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                   IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                   IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White"
                      Padding="10">
                    <!-- Define item appearance -->
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

For more information, check document : [Context menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data#context-menus).

You can also check the sample here : [CollectionViewDemos](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos). Especially pay attention to page : [VerticalListSwipeContextItemsPage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Swipe/VerticalListSwipeContextItemsPage.xaml).